# Reading value from file and counting the number of each status

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, file

I have txt file and it have these Bmi values :

```
18.9
20.4
16.5
28.7
34.2
24.5
17.2
29.7
23.2
```

So if I have this code here

```py
if ( bmi < 18.5):
   Status ="underweight"

elif ( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 24.5):
   Status = "normal"

elif ( bmi >= 24.5 and bmi <29.9):
   Status = "overweight "

elif ( bmi >= 30.0):
   Status = "Obesity"
```

Now I want to count number of each of this status from that values are in txt files I hope it’s clear

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the lines from your file and for each line, convert the line to a floating point number, do your check, and then add to the counter variables.

(replace `values.txt` with a path to your file)

```py
with open("values.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    underweight = 0
    normal = 0
    overweight = 0
    obese = 0

    for line in lines:
        bmi = float(line)

        if ( bmi < 18.5): 
            underweight += 1
        elif ( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 24.5):
            underweight += 1
        elif ( bmi >= 24.5 and bmi <29.9):
            overweight += 1
        elif ( bmi >= 30.0):
            obese += 1
```

You can then print out `underweight` and your other variables just like any other variable:

```
print(underweight)
print(normal)
print(overweight)
print(obese)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing code, you could create a function to return the BMI status:

```
def get_bmi_status(bmi):
    if bmi < 18.5: 
        return "underweight"

    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 24.5: 
        return "normal"

    elif bmi >= 24.5 and bmi < 29.9: 
        return "overweight"

    elif bmi >= 30.0: 
        return "Obesity"
```

Then you could read your file line by line, convert to `float`, and collect the counts in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("data.txt") as f:
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for bmi in f:
        status = get_bmi_status(float(bmi.strip()))
        counts[status] += 1

    print(counts)
```

Which will give you these counts:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'normal': 3, 'underweight': 2, 'overweight': 3, 'Obesity': 1})
```

We could also get the counts with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("data.txt") as f:
    counts = Counter(get_bmi_status(float(bmi.strip())) for bmi in f)
    print(counts)
```

Which will give instead:

```
Counter({'normal': 3, 'overweight': 3, 'underweight': 2, 'Obesity': 1})
```

Both `defaultdict` and `Counter` are subclasses of `dict`, so you can use them like a regular dictionary.